# Doubt Regarding Magento Subdomain Creation

Tags: multistore

We have developing a e-commerce website in magento. We have two type of products.

1. Electrical
2. Apparels

We need to set-up two sub-domain for same Magento installation.What are the steps for achieving this?

I need urls looks like this.

1. electrical.example.com
2. apparels.example.com

Answer (score 3):

you can refer [official magento documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) to manage your domain

Your htaccess code should be like this

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.electrical.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=elecw
SetEnvIf Host www\.electrical.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^electrical.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=elecw
SetEnvIf Host ^electrical.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website


SetEnvIf Host www\.apparels.example\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=appaw
SetEnvIf Host www\.apparels.example\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^apparels.example\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=appaw
SetEnvIf Host ^apparels.example\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

you can set your store code as per your convenience.

Hope this will sure help you.